# Open in Safari from UIWebView (using youtube.com)

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, youtube

This has been the most frustrating thing I've ever had the misfortune of doing, ever. I have a UIWebView. It goes to http://m.youtube.com. I want any subsequent link I press to then be sent to Safari, not the UIWebView. Simple, right? Here's the code you'll find over and over again:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

But this doesn't work. So I changed `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked` to `UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther`. This instantly open in Safari when the view loads. Again not what I want. So I did this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther) {

        NSLog(@"It works!");

//        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
       return YES;
   }

   return NO;
}
```

to check if subsequent clicks even go through here and they don't. The log only shows "It works!" when the view initially loads. Any subsequent clicks show nothing.

So I've tried looking out for a URL change and Javascript change but still nothing. Is there anything else I can do?

**(By the way I should mention that this code does work on any other website, like stackoverflow.com - any subsequent link clicks and I'm taken to Safari. It only doesn't work with YouTube)**

This is what I get from the log when I press a link on youtube:

```
2013-01-24 21:08:25.886 HatFilms[30079:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-01-24 21:08:25.886 HatFilms[30079:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
2013-01-24 21:08:25.887 HatFilms[30079:c07] setting movie path: http://r1---sn-5n3-n1qe.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?mv=m&mt=1359061639&ms=au&yms=Ag6pZvjqA20&source=youtube&key=yt1&el=watch&upn=g2ConWh5QJ0&id=201015c58a31c984&cp=U0hUTlBTVF9LS0NONF9ITVhCOlhkN3FFcm5zWDY5&ip=31.205.57.12&newshard=yes&fexp=909714%2C901802%2C919358%2C914066%2C916625%2C902534%2C920704%2C912806%2C922403%2C922405%2C929901%2C913605%2C925710%2C929104%2C920201%2C913302%2C919009%2C911116%2C926403%2C910221%2C901451&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&sver=3&expire=1359086161&dnc=1&app=youtube_mobile&ratebypass=yes&itag=18&signature=A434075DABFEBB44E5F0588B7430D04A931684B0.648F49C3F4D254E29B970A6AA68BAC1C08280B97&ipbits=8
2013-01-24 21:08:25.887 HatFilms[30079:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-01-24 21:08:25.895 HatFilms[30079:c07] [MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
```

And if I log everything that the UIWebView receives:

```
2013-01-24 21:50:31.642 HatFilms[30372:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-01-24 21:50:31.642 HatFilms[30372:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
2013-01-24 21:50:31.642 HatFilms[30372:c07] setting movie path: http://r1---sn-5n3-n1qe.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?expire=1359086161&key=yt1&sver=3&app=youtube_mobile&el=watch&signature=44DA69CF58A649EAA813EE2A8E91B38BB164CB9D.2DA718585DEDB6F55E4ABBDD247602E713981C83&source=youtube&upn=3Qgzgd7FAjY&newshard=yes&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=8&itag=18&yms=Ag6pZvjqA20&fexp=909714%2C901802%2C919358%2C914066%2C916625%2C902534%2C920704%2C912806%2C922403%2C922405%2C929901%2C913605%2C925710%2C929104%2C920201%2C913302%2C919009%2C911116%2C926403%2C910221%2C901451&ip=31.205.57.12&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&cp=U0hUTlBTVF9LS0NONF9ITVhCOlhkN3FFcm5zWDY5&dnc=1&id=201015c58a31c984&mv=m&mt=1359064215&ms=au
2013-01-24 21:50:31.643 HatFilms[30372:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-01-24 21:50:31.646 HatFilms[30372:c07] [MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
2013-01-24 21:50:32.333 HatFilms[30372:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
2013-01-24 21:50:32.349 HatFilms[30372:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 0 -> 1
2013-01-24 21:50:32.350 HatFilms[30372:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
2013-01-24 21:50:32.768 HatFilms[30372:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-01-24 21:50:32.786 HatFilms[30372:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: When you say 'this doesn't work' — did you do anything like log every request/navigationType you're given and try to figure out what you are getting from YouTube?

Comment: All I get through the log is some stuff about auto play. I've added it to my original post.

Comment: But if you specifically log what your delegate receives?

Comment: I've added that to the original post