# Reload a UIWebView every request?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView and I'm trying to get links to open in Safari. The usual code works, just not with m.youtube.com. So I'm trying a different approach - is there a way of, every time the webView is loading, the page is completely reloaded but with the new URL instead? This is the only solution I can think of.

Here is the question I'm referencing:

[Open in Safari from UIWebView (using youtube.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510191/open-in-safari-from-uiwebview-using-youtube-com/14514058#comment20251699_14514058)

Thanks.

Comment: Check the `webViewDidStartLoad` and grab the URL that it's attempting to load then `[UIWebView stop];` (stop the loading) then load that URL manually? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: ^Either way the Youtube App being opened is something done by Apple.. so even if you manually load it into safari using NSUrl SharedApplication or whatever the UIWebView itself will still redirect you to youtube.

Comment: ^I thinly our best bet would to be to look into YouTubes URL parameters and maybe find something that prevent it from opening the YouTube app on an iOS device. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: This is what I want. I want any link that is clicked on the youtube site in my webView to be loaded in either Safari or the YouTube app. I just can't figure out how to do it, since the usual code (using shouldStartLoadWithRequest) works with every site except YouTube and I can't figure out why.

Comment: No, it definatley should work with Youtube... your problem is that YouTube operates on a different bases than just URL redirects... for example they may have something thats youtube.com/blah and you click a button and it stays on that page but the URL changes to youtube.com/blah#blahblah ... The "#" is key... shouldSTARTwithRequest is the wrong function because that is only called when the page is first loaded... not when the URL changes... you need to get the pages full URL (maybe by querying your UIWebView with Javascript) and then check it for changes with an NSTimer then reload the new URL